# quote vs ' in customization file

Tags: customize

I sync my config between several different machines using git. Setting options via the `customize-variable` interface, some of my computers use `quote`, while others use `'`. As a consequence, my git commits include lots of bouncing back and forth like this:

```
  '(ess-r-prettify-symbols
-   (quote
-    (("<-" 129032)
+   '(("<-" 129032)
      ("->" 32
```

I'm not editing these values by hand, so something in Emacs is deciding whether or not to use the word or symbol for quote. It's driving me batty - how do I tell Emacs to always use one or the other?

Comment: Different emacs versions on the various machines? What version(s)?

Comment: @NickD I was building from source, with one computer pointing at the github mirror, and the other at the git repo at savanna. After rebuilding both machines using the same commit, the problem is gone. If you make an answer I'll give you some internet points!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Just expanding the comment into an answer, so I can get some internet points from Tyler :-) ]

I guessed that different versions of emacs might have different implementations of `customize`: some using `quote` explicitly and others using `'`, so the resulting custom files would be at war with each other. I guess I guessed right :-) (well, not really as @rpluim points out in a comment).

Comment: It's actually a change in the default value of `print-quoted`, which is now `t`. That changed in emacs-27

Comment: Thanks for identifying the culprit!