# Why has my .custom file changed between `(quote` syntax and the `'` syntax and how to convert between the two?

Tags: customize, quote

I use the same `.custom` file on different machines syncronised via a git repo.

I just noticed that suddenly the `.custom` file from one machine uses the `(quote` syntax while in the past the  `'` syntax was used (or vice versa). Two questions:

1. Why is this happening? Is there a change in, say, Emacs 27? (On *one* machine I have upgarded to 27.)
2. How can I convert manually between the two syntaxes, so that I can diff teh files sensibly?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [quote vs ' in customization file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/59024/quote-vs-in-customization-file)

Comment: @Tyler Thanks for the cross link. Makes sense. - Still have to find a way to convert for consistency... see my comment below.

Comment: @Drew Not sure, how the tag link helps, sorry. Could you give details, pls?

Comment: It tells you that tag `elisp` is not for questions about how to do something in Elisp. It's for questions about the nature of the language, in particular wrt other Lisp dialects. And nearly every Emacs question gets into how to do something with Elisp.

Comment: @Drew I see. Make sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a change in emacs-27, from etc/NEWS:

```
** 'print-quoted' now defaults to t, so if you want to see
'(quote x)' instead of 'x you will have to bind it to nil where applicable.
```

So binding `print-quoted` to your desired value and then saving a
customization should be enough.

Comment: Thanks. This points me definitely in the right direction! Now I just have to find out how to convert the file always to the same syntax - As long as I have 26er Emacses around I guess a crud temporary solution can be to set `print-quoetd` globally to `nil` - but I hope this doesn't break anything in the one Emacs 27 I use...

Comment: I don't think binding `print-quoted` to nil will break anything